# Serialize file bytes from C# to SQL Server and Back Again

Tags: c#, sql

I have an app where I'm chunking up file bytes and storing each chunk in a database (I'm logging info around each chunk). Then, I'm trying to retrieve the chunks from the database, put them back together in C# and write to a file.

Currently, I have the following C# code:

```
string encoded = GetBase64EncodedFile();  // This is just for readability
byte[] fileBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encoded).ToList().ToArray();

Database database = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
using (DbCommand command = database.GetStoredProcCommand("SaveFileChunk"))
{
  database.AddInParameter(command, "fileName", DbType.String, fileName);
  database.AddInParameter(command, "offset", DbType.Int32, offset);
  database.AddInParameter(command, "number", DbType.Int32, number);
  database.AddInParameter(command, "chunkBytes", DbType.Binary, fileBytes);

  database.ExecuteNonQuery(command);
}
```

At this point, if I print out fileBytes.Count(), I see: 152754

The record is written to a SQL Azure table with the following structure:

```
FileChunk
---------
Filename nvarchar(max)
Offset int
Number int
ChunkBytes varbinary(max)
```

Later, I try to receive the file chunks with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM [FileChunk] ORDER BY [Number]
```

I then try to populate my FileChunk CLR object as follows:

```
public FileChunk(IDataReader reader)
{
  fileName = reader["Filename"].ToString();
  offset = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Offset"].ToString());
  number = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Number"].ToString());
  chunkBytes = reader["ChunkBytes"].ToString().ToCharArray().Select(c => (byte)c).ToArray();
}
```

When I execute this code, I've learned that chunkBytes.Count() above is 13.

This means that I have some sort of serialization or data type conversion error. However, I don't see it. How do I a) Put the bytes into SQL Azure b) Get them back out

Thank you

Comment: You are over converting types. First I'd recommend you to use File.ReadAllBytes instead of converting it to Base64 and all that. Then do NOT EVER read the bytes off a varbinary column into a string like you did - just get the bytes directly like Nikola said.

Answer (score 2):

Simply cast `reader["ChunkBytes"]` to byte array.

It is not necessary to call `ToString()` for each and every field of your reader and then convert it to actual types. It tremendously hurts performance - you can directly cast integers to `int`, varchars and such to `string` and binary fields to `byte[]`:

```
public FileChunk(IDataReader reader)
{
    fileName = (string)reader["Filename"];
    offset = (int)reader["Offset"];
    number = (int)reader["Number"];
    chunkBytes = (byte[])reader["ChunkBytes"];
}
```

As a sidenote - do you have a specific reason to use ADO.NET instead of some ORM solution like LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework? Having written my share of ADO.NET code, I would nowadays use it only for very specific projects indeed - e.g. when you need to manually create your statement.